# How to access IBM DB2 warehouse on cloud as administrator

Tags: database, db2, ibm-cloud

I'm currently using a free DB2 warehouse on cloud provided by IBM. What I'm trying to do is to create a new table in the database. However, an error message pops up saying that
[image]
To resolve this, I open the web console and run the following command: `create tablespace mytablespace pagesize 4096`. Then, another error message pops up:
[image]

Based on what I have googled, it looks like I need to grant administrator role for the user "DASH******". So I do this by adding an optional parameter to the credentials:
[image]

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to workaround this?

**EDIT1:** I create the table using the following command:
[image]

Comment: What's the exact `CREATE TABLE` (and not `CREATE TABLESPACE`) statement you tried?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I just edit the post.

Comment: Did I get you right that you issue this `CREATE TABLE` statement, and get SQLCODE=-552 on the `CREATE TABLESPACE` operation?

Comment: The error message is "A table space could not be found with a page size of at least "4096" that authorization ID "DASH******" is authorized to use.. SQLCODE=-286, SQLSTATE=42727, DRIVER=4.24.92"

Answer (score 1):

Users are not allowed to create their own tablespaces in free `DB2WoC` systems, since they don't have the `SYSCTRL` or `SYSADM` authorities there. You have to use existing tablespaces where you are allowed to create your tables.
Run the following statement from your `DASH***` user.
This statement returns all the tablespaces, where your user is allowed to create tables.
If it doesn't return any rows, then this means, that you should open a ticket to the IBM support. Support should create it for you and grant your user the `USE` privilege on this tablespace.

```
SELECT  
  T.DATATYPE
--, P.PRIVILEGE
--, P.OBJECTTYPE
--, P.OBJECTSCHEMA
, P.OBJECTNAME
, U.AUTHID, U.AUTHIDTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P
CROSS JOIN TABLE(VALUES USER) A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE (
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.AUTHID AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.AUTHIDTYPE
JOIN SYSCAT.TABLESPACES T ON T.TBSPACE=P.OBJECTNAME
WHERE P.OBJECTTYPE='TABLESPACE' AND T.DATATYPE IN ('A', 'L')
```